# SQS Event Source not being created on AWS SAM Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-sam

Please help. I have an AWS Lambda defined in an AWS SAM YAML file that has been deployed but does not create the event source along with it. Please, what could I likely be missing here? I have already tried adding certain permissions to the SQS and SQSPoller permissions to the Lambda but that did not work. I have already spent too much time on this already. Thank you very much

```
  BootstrapFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Zip
      FunctionName: !Sub '${appName}-${env}-${sourceCodeName}-bootstrap'
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Ref sourceCodeBucketName
        Key: !Sub '${sourceCodeName}/${sourceCodeTag}.zip'
      Description: Bootstrap the Project State Machine
      Handler: build/src/bootstrapHandler.bootstrap
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaExecute
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 1024
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_LEVEL: 'debug'
          REGION: !Ref AWS::Region
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref clusterSecurityGroupId
        SubnetIds: !Ref subnetIds
    Events:
      BootstrapFunctionSQSEvent:
        Type: SQS
        Properties:
          Queue: !GetAtt TaskQueue.Arn
          BatchSize: 1
          Enabled: true

TaskQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub '${appName}-${env}-${sourceCodeName}-task'
      MessageRetentionPeriod: !Ref sqsMessageRetentionSeconds
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt TaskDlQueue.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: !Ref maxReceiveCountForDlq

  TaskQueueWritePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: !Sub '${appName}-${env}-${sourceCodeName}-task-queue-write-policy'
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowQueueAccess
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sqs:SendMessage
              - sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt TaskQueue.Arn

  TaskQueueReadPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: !Sub '${appName}-${env}-${sourceCodeName}-task-queue-read-policy'
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowQueueAccess
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility
              - sqs:ReceiveMessage
              - sqs:DeleteMessage
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt TaskQueue.Arn
```

Comment: How did you test so that you know it does not work? If you just checked for tirggers in AWS console, it may be false positive. Have you actually tried using your app?

Comment: I checked in the AWS Console and it is not a false positive. @jd-d just has answered my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Events` should be indented underneath `Properties` in your `BootstrapFunction` resource:

```yaml
  BootstrapFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Zip
      FunctionName: !Sub '${appName}-${env}-${sourceCodeName}-bootstrap'
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Ref sourceCodeBucketName
        Key: !Sub '${sourceCodeName}/${sourceCodeTag}.zip'
      Description: Bootstrap the Project State Machine
      Handler: build/src/bootstrapHandler.bootstrap
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaExecute
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 1024
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_LEVEL: 'debug'
          REGION: !Ref AWS::Region
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref clusterSecurityGroupId
        SubnetIds: !Ref subnetIds
      Events:
        BootstrapFunctionSQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt TaskQueue.Arn
            BatchSize: 1
            Enabled: true
```